# Conversion of datatype through macro in C

Tags: c, types, macros

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define int long
int main ()
{
  char c;
  int i=0;
  char str[]="Example sentence to test isspace\n";
  while (str[i])
  {
    c=str[i];
    if (isspace(c)) c='\n';
    putchar (c);
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It gives error on linux environment, because: 
`isspace` will be expanded as

```
if (((*__ctype_b_loc ())[(int) ((c))] & (unsigned short int) _ISspace)) c='\n';
```

As I changed int to long through macro, it will become

```
if (((*__ctype_b_loc ())[(long) ((c))] & (unsigned short long) _ISspace)) c='\n';
```

Hence it throws error, Please provide me with the answer.

Comment: Defining a macro that matches any C reserved word leads to undefined behavior.  So don't do that.

Comment: If you would tell us the error that the compiler (?) give you, we could perhaps help you to solve the real issue. Tempering with platform defined types or macros certainly isn't a valid solution

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: **Don't change int to long with a macro.**

If you really must you can can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define int long
int main ()
{
  char c;
  int i=0;
  char str[]="Example sentence to test isspace\n";
  while (str[i])
  {
    c=str[i];
#define int int
    if (isspace(c)) c='\n';
#define int long
    putchar (c);
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: even this is still hideous. why not just use an int like isspace expects?

Comment: @user931794 - I agree, but maybe there is other stuff in the system that needs the define, so this will at least work.

Comment: Hi, I did the same what you suggested Thank you verymuch,

Comment: @ranganath111 - My first and only suggestion is to not use `#define int long` -- that is what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define int long
```

This is a very bad idea. Don't do this.

> It gives error on linux environment

No it doesn't. Compiles and executes just fine with gcc.

> As I changed int to long through macro

This is a very bad idea. Don't do this.

The answer to your question is: if you try to re-invent the C language with macros, bad things will happen and you are left on your own to solve them.